# How can I search Supabase database in React Admin using ilike instead of eq filter?

Tags: react-admin, supabase

I have a react admin application linked to my supabase database. I have a posts table in this database. My aim is to be able to search the titles of these posts via react admin.
For example, I have two posts {id:1, title: "first post"} and {id:2, title: "second post"}. When I do a search for "second" using this code :

```js
const postFilters = [
    <TextInput source="title" label="Search by title" alwaysOn />,
];

export const PostList = () => (
    <List filters={postFilters} >
      <Datagrid >
        <TextField source="id" />
        <TextField source="title" />
        <EditButton />
        <ShowButton />
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

It doesn't return any results because it wants a strict equality. If I type "second post" as search term, it will give me the result expected.

I have tried to change my  by a  like that : `<SearchInput source="title" alwaysOn />` but it don't change anything.

I can see on my database logs this url : `/post?title=eq.second`. I think if I can be able to change `title=eq.second` to somthing like `title=ilike.second` it should work but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for giving me the idea to check the source code of my DataProvider @MaxAlex.
I use `ra-data-postgrest` and after reading its README in `node_modules`, I saw that we can simply do this :
`<TextInput source="title@ilike" label="Search by title" alwaysOn />`.

Answer (score 0):

[General information about Filter Operators](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/FilteringTutorial.html#filter-operators)

The final request to server is formed inside your DataProvider.
You need to change implementation of DataProvider `getList` method.

You can do this in various ways:

1. Clone the source code of your DataProvider and change the implementation of `getList`.
2. Implement a [wrapper](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#handling-file-uploads) for the original DataProvider in the same way.
   Inside it, change the query parameters and call the original DataProvider with the new parameters.
3. Use the [withLifecycleCallbacks()](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/withLifecycleCallbacks.html) method to decorate the DataProvider.
   Inside the `beforeGetList(params, dataProvider)`, override params and return new parameters.